# Change button background with using 'getElementById'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using data tables to show data and a button is present opposite to each entry of my data table.

That button has onclick which captures the parameter present in a row and save in array.

I want to change color when certain entry is selected and reset on deselect.

Here is what I am doing,

```
function select(name){
        var property = document.getElementByClassName('checkRule');
        if( rArray.includes(name) ){
            
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
            const index = rArray.indexOf(name);
              if (index > -1) {
                  rArray.splice(index, 1);
              }
            
        }else{
            rArray.push(name);
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#28a0ff"
        }
        
        console.log('ARRAY >> ', rArray);
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-12 table-design">
      
      <div class="row panel panel-default c-panel">
      <div class="panel-heading c-phead">EMPLOYEE LIST</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="c_table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Employer</th>
              
              <th scope="col">Checked/Unchecked</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${e_list}" varStatus="status" var="emp">
                <tr>      
                    <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
                    <td>${emp.getEmpName()}</td>
                    <td>${emp.getEmployer()}</td>
                    <td>
                      <button type="button"  class="custom-control-input checkRule" id="checkRule" onclick="selectRule('${emp.getEmpName()}')"></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This code is only changing color of very first element of of data table.

How shall I make it work?

Comment: I don't have any information of your html code, but I think "Id" is a unique value and if you use ```.getElementById``` then it will select the first element with that id. Try to call them using class name.

Comment: It seems you have same id of every button and that will work only for first occurrence. You can generate dynamic IDs of each button. for that you can use primary key of your table (if using database).

Comment: Please show me your html and datatable code i'll try to solve your problem

Comment: @ritzy I reread your question and it seems that you only want to change the row/element of the button that was clicked. In that case, you can make use of the `this` keyword inside of your `select()` function instead of using `getElementsById()` etc. and intead use `this` to refer to the element which you click on

Comment: "I want to change color when certain entry is selected" what do you want to change the color of? the table row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the below solution.

1. Add extra unique key with id see your id parameter below
2. Pass extra unique key with onclick event as second param
3. get that second param in your js function and add that in getElemetById.

```js
function select(name,***Uid***){
        var property = document.getElementById('checkRule'***+Uid***);
        if( rArray.includes(name) ){
            
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
            const index = rArray.indexOf(name);
              if (index > -1) {
                  rArray.splice(index, 1);
              }
            
        }else{
            rArray.push(name);
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#28a0ff"
        }
        
        console.log('ARRAY >> ', rArray);
    }
```

```html
<button type="button"  class="custom-control-input checkRule" id="checkRule***${status.index + 1}***" onclick="selectRule('${emp.getEmpName()}','${status.index + 1}')"></button>
```

Comment: Avoid using stars when implementing the code. it is just to highlight the changes

Comment: You can instead pass through the event: `onclick="selectRule('${emp.getEmpName()}', event)">`, now you can access the element clicked using: `var property = event.target`

Comment: yes you're right. but actually @ritzy need to clear the things why and how IDs works.

Comment: Thank you guys.... it worked just perfectly as expected

Comment: @ritzy you should upvote this so this can help others too.

Comment: @Nads...My reputation is low to do so :(

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend changing the background color using `closest` and `toggle` -

```js
function select(element) {
  element.closest("tr").classList.toggle("colored-bg");
  // Additional code to store in array if required
}
```

```css
.colored-bg {
  background-color: #28a0ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 table-design">

  <div class="row panel panel-default c-panel">
    <div class="panel-heading c-phead">EMPLOYEE LIST</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table table-striped" id="c_table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Employer</th>

            <th scope="col">Checked/Unchecked</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>name1</td>
            <td>emp1</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="custom-control-input checkRule" id="checkRule" onclick="select(this)">Click</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>name2</td>
            <td>emp2</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="custom-control-input checkRule" onclick="select(this)">Click</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>name3</td>
            <td>emp3</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="custom-control-input checkRule" onclick="select(this)">Click</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```